# Gradle Sync Failed: ERROR: Expected ':' at line 1 column 11 path $.please

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I open a this android project but when it wants to build a project it said this
[image: here the error]

The point is that I have never changed my gradle files.

I've invalidated caches and restart Android Studio.

But it didn't work.

I have no idea what caused this problem. Anyone here can help me?

here's the log:

```
org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 1 column 11 path $.please
    at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:84)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:59)
    at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask.action(GoogleServicesTask.java:163)
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 1 column 11 path $.please
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1568)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:530)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:700)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:723)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:698)
    at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:48)
```

gradle.build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
//apply plugin: 'android-apt'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.st.jobportal"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

(Project Level)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'  // Google Services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

(Module level)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

//apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.st.jobportal"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I think you don't need Fabric because you don't use Crashlystics nor Fabric.

If it fails, then Invalid & Clean. If it's successful then, only the way you can try is

Comment: I remove Fabric but problem not changed @c-an

Comment: @SamadTalukder What is your Android Studio version?

Comment: Android Studio version : 3.5.3 @c-an

Comment: Remove all fabric things & `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` too.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove all Fabric dependencies mean :

1. remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
2. remove `apply plugin: 'io.fabric`'

3.remove

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

4.remove

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

After all, steps make the project and all things be fixed!

Comment: Sorry bro after all steps make the project don't be fixed

Comment: oh, but fixed for me. please take care to do all thing carefully